# Updating Database using Promises doesn't return updated Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js, es6-promise

Updating multiple records in database with Sequelize using Promise.all:

```
db.Diet.findAll({
        where: {
            id: dietIds
        }
}).then((existingDiets) => {

existingDiets.forEach(function (aDiet, index) {
            var updatedObj = diets.filter(function (obj) {
                return (obj.id === aDiet.id);
            })

            if (updatedObj[0]) {
                if (updatedObj[0].name != aDiet.name) {
                    aDiet.name = updatedObj[0].name
                }
                existingDiets[index] = aDiet
            }
        })

        db.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
            var promises = []
            for (var i = 0; i < existingDiets.length; i++) {
                console.log("i " + i)
                var newPromise = existingDiets[i].save().then((Diet) => {
                    console.log("new Prom Diet " + Diet)
                }, {transaction: t});
               promises.push(newPromise);
            };

            return Promise.all(promises).then(function(updatedDiets) {
                console.log("updatedDiets " + updatedDiets)
            });
        }).then(function (results) {
            console.log("results " + results)            
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("NO!!! " + err);
            return next(err);
        });
   })
```

Console:

```
Express listening on port 3000!
i 0
i 1
i 2
```

The objects in the DB are indeed updated, but aren't returned and thus, aren't logged in the console.  Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you are not returning anything in the `then` when you save the existingDiets - have you tried adding something like `return Diet;`?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I did try it just now but no avail.  Plus, nothing is logged for `console.log("new Prom Diet " + Diet)`

Comment: in docs it says "chain all your queries here. make sure you return them." - I would add returns to all `then`s in the transaction - if that doesn't work out than the problem is somwhere else maybe logic or validation, source http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html

Comment: `.then((Diet) => {
                    console.log("new Prom Diet " + Diet)
                }, {transaction: t});` ... results in "onresolved" returning undefined because all you're doing is a console.log and no return, and the onrejected function in that .then is passed an object, so, it is ignored (i.e. `{transaction: t}` is not at all relevant to the code)

Comment: Thanks.  I did try doing return Diet but didn't do anything.